# Can we remove this tag from our [portfolio]?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I came across the [portfolio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/portfolio) tag in the usual way today (tagged in a bad question that had nothing to do with it), and am very curious why this tag exists on Stack Overflow - it doesn't seem to have anything to do with programming, isn't something anyone can be an expert in, and even in the tag wiki seems to cover a bunch of things that are unrelated (art portfolio, stock portfolio, patent portfolio are all mentioned, for example).

I suggest we burninate it.  There are 400 questions tagged [portfolio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/portfolio), and apparently 40 people following it for some reason I can't fathom.

Comment: Please read through [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191) and address each point explicitly in your question. I know you did touch on all of them, but if you make it easy for people to read, they won't think you didn't :)

Comment: I feel like this is similar to the [dashboard] tag which is also up for burnination...such general terms that can't possibly better explain context without wordy questions.

Answer (score 33):

This is not a programming tag. I say we burn portfolio and stick to collections. *(that was some weak attempt at programming humour)*

Comment: I agree - we should burn it.

Answer (score 5):

Here's the tag usage guidance:

> Portfolio may refer to: a collection of held stocks or investments (finance), or patents held by a single entity; a sample of an individual's past work (art, education, photography, development), or a display case (physical or virtual) used to display artwork, photographs, etc.

The fact that it's listing a bunch of things (none of which are *even vaguely* related to programming) should tell you about the quality of this tag. How are display cases used to display artwork, for example, related in any meaningful way to programming?

Clearly,

- This tag is ambiguous
- The tag does *not* mean the same thing in all common contexts, as the usage guidance itself effectively admits
- Literally all of the suggested uses are blatantly off-topic (they have nothing whatsoever to do with programming), unless we want to start accepting questions on painting or photography here.
- The tag is so vague that it adds no useful information to the question.

That being the case, can we burninate this?

Answer (score 4):

[Portfolio optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portfolio_optimization) seems like a collection of mathematical techniques and as I see it programming can be applied to solve it.

Examples:

- [Looping viewFinancials from quantmod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42047746/looping-viewfinancials-from-quantmod)
- [Error in constrOptim, initial value not in the interior of the feasible region](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42328705/error-in-constroptim-initial-value-not-in-the-interior-of-the-feasible-region)
- [R/PortfolioAnalytics optimize.portfolio()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42012390/r-portfolioanalytics-optimize-portfolio)

I agree that we don't need to tag questions where people try to build their portfolio management system, because in those cases the tag doesn't really help categorize the question:

- [Quick Page/Post Redirect Plugin Plugin for Wordpress will not open links in a New Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42321016/quick-page-post-redirect-plugin-plugin-for-wordpress-will-not-open-links-in-a-ne)
- [HTML content isnt showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42463640/html-content-isnt-showing-up)
- [Joomla, assing menu-item to particular user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42925729/joomla-assing-menu-item-to-particular-user)

I'm not at all familiar with portfolio optimization, but it looks as though it warrants its own tag. Maybe there are others.

Comment: maybe a rename to portfolio-optimization then ?

Comment: @Walfrat is just the name of the problem. Like the knapsack problem, traveling salesman problem, etc. It's actual name is "maximizing a quadratic function".

Comment: "Looping viewFinancials from quantmod" question is about financial portfolios. Don't let the R code confuse you!

Comment: Good point, however, the mathematical tools used for portfolio optimisation are more relevant here. Portfolio optimisation is still something that is within the business domain and not relevant to use this term within the programming domain. It needs to be broken up into a use case that is relevant for programming.